What is this black teardrop-shaped object under the C-47 Skytrain cockpit?
I was recently at the Airborne Museum in Sainte-Mère-Église, France, and I saw a C-47 Skytrain for the first time in person. I saw that, under the cockpit, there was a black, teardrop-shaped object. I couldn't figure out what it was.

What is it, and what is it for?

Related: What is the vertical rod on this Swissair DC-3 drawing?

According to the following cutaway (source) that's simply the fairing of the ADF (automatic direction finder) antenna (number 24):


Within the fairing

Very informative picture.  I can now improve the description I learned many years ago for the C-47 / DC-3 / Dakota.  I can now call it "A collection of one hundred and thirty-five parts flying in loose formation."  Citation for the "Collection of parts" reference: https://www.bbc.com/culture/article/20131009-dc3-still-flying-at-70

I suspect there's a little more than 135 parts.

@ceejayoz 135 Spanish line items, perhaps ?

Call it 136 then: all the above, plus: "136: Miscellaneous"
